# Xpath, how to get access to inner elements?

Tags: xpath

```
<div class="vehicle-item__main-content">
  <div class=class="vehicle-item_summary-container">
    <ul class="vehicle-item__attributes">
      <li class="vehicle-item__attribute-item">
        <i class="icon icon-specs-transmission-gray"></i>
        "Manual"
      </li>
      <li class="vehicle-item__attribute-item">
        <i class="icon icon-specs-passenger-gray">
        "4 People"
      </li>
```

I have a webscraper andI would like to catch the following texts, 'Manual' and '4 People'. The website has many more class="vehicle-item__attribute-item" which I dont need. How can I get access to the text ? Maybe by using the help of the i class (class="icon icon-specs-transmission-gray")

```
transmission = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[@class="vehicle-item__attribute-item"]')

transmissionlist = []

    for trans in transmission:
        print(trans.text)
        transmissionlist.append(trans.text)
```

With this I am getting all 100+ items from the website, but I only need the above 2 car properties.

Comment: How did you try? Show us

Comment: Pls check, I added my code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of

```
'//li[@class="vehicle-item__attribute-item"]'
```

try

```
'//li[i[contains(@class, "icon-specs-transmission-gray")]]'
'//li[i[contains(@class, "icon-specs-passenger-gray")]]'

transmission = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[i[contains(@class, "icon-specs-transmission-gray")]]').text
passengers = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[i[contains(@class, "icon-specs-passenger-gray")]]').text
```

Comment: Thx a lot JaSON, this was the expression I needed. I can use this with my other scripts aswell. Appreciate it